How do proponents of the rapture account for 1 Thessalonians 4:14, which seems to refute the concept?
In 1 Thessalonians 4:14 Paul tells us that the people that He refers to as "sleeping" will rise from the dead just like Jesus.

1Th 4:14 For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so, them also which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him.

Jesus both died and was resurrected on earth.
Meaning that Paul was speaking here about the earthly resurrection that He referred to in Romans 6:13.
Meaning that the "sleepers" are backslidden believers.

Rm 6:13 Neither yield ye your members as instruments of unrighteousness unto sin: but yield yourselves unto God, as those that are alive from the dead, and your members as instruments of righteousness unto God.

I am curious to find out how rapturists deal with this.

The question would be improved by adding an explicit statement as to exactly what needs to be dealt with.

Not sure exactly what you mean, although I had considered adding references from Romans 6 which alludes to the Christain life as the resurrected life in Christ (similar to Colossians 3:1).

From the question, I don't see any obvious conflict that anyone would need to deal with. What is the problem you perceive?

Up-voted, but, yes, some more explanation and detail is needed as not everyone will immediately see the implications that the OP has seen.

It's been updated, but it's still not obvious why rapturists would need to deal with it. What exactly is their problem with these facts?

Their whole deluded Rapture concept rests on them going to heaven in the Rapture. Paul is in 4:14 refering to the events that happened to Jesus on earth. These events will happen to Jesus followers while they are on earth as well. Hence the comparison which uses the phrase "even so" meaning in "like manner".

It's still not clear how what precedes it can be seen as "Meaning that the "sleepers" are backslidden believers.". Why do you claim it means that? ¶ The question seems to be presenting an argument against something, but it neglects to mention what that something is.

Paul's concept of what is called the "first resurrection" is very clear in scripture. It is walikng in newness of life as Romans 6:11. He applies this concept to other believers when He refes to them as already having experienced a resurrection in Col 3:1. This resurrection is interuppted when they sin. Upon willful sin they are scripturally refered to as "dead in Christ". Dead while they live.

https://www.brmicke.com/?p=4965

My insights are informed by the knowledge I've gained through my studies at Christian Leaders Institute. My theological framework is founded on a Non-denominational Trinitarian perspective. I am receptive to discussing any perspective or addressing any inquiries related to my response.
Logic of verse 14. Followed by its context.
Logical link between two halves of this verse not explicitly stated: how does verse 14a ("For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again") logically lead to verse 14b ("so also God will bring with him those who have fallen asleep")?
Paul's logic, however, is clear from an understanding of his theology found elsewhere in his letters. In Paul's way of thinking (his theology), Christ's resurrection is a guarantee of believers' resurrection.
Rom 8:11 "And if the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead is living you, he who raised Christ from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through his Spirit, who lives in you."
1 Cor 6:14 "By his power God raised the Lord from the dead, and he will raise us also [from the dead]."
2 Cor 4:14 "because we know that the one who raised the Lord Jesus from the dead will also raise us with Jesus ..."
Col 1:18 "he [Jesus] is the firstborn from among the dead."
1 Cor 15:12-23 "But if it is preached that Christ has been raised from the dead, how can some of you say that there is no resurrection of the dead? ...For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive."
1 Cor 15:20 "But Christ has indeed been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep."
Paul's logic in verse 14 is now clear Christ's resurrection (v 14a) is a "firstfruit” or guarantee of believers' resurrection which means that the Thessalonians' fellow believers who have already died will be raised at Christ's return so that "God will bring with Jesus those who have fallen asleep in him." (v 14b) Deceased believers will not miss out or be at a disadvantage at Christ's return!
Q: Is the rapture a biblical teaching or mistaken idea?
A: Answer must come from examining these key verses grammatically, historically and theologically
(Soft) Evidence #1: The public nature of Christ's coming.
Three prepositional phrases (with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trumpet call of God) point not to a secret coming in which Christians will suddenly and quietly vanish but a public return of Christ which all people--both believers and unbelievers alike--will witness.
(Soft) Evidence #2: "will be caught up" Greek verb "harpazo" used by many ancient writers to refer to people being "snatched away” from life to death.
Plutarch: uses verb harpazo and its compounds to refer to those who die an early death such that they are "snatched away" from "the advantages of life, such as marriage, education, manhood, citizenship and public office” (A Letter of Condolence to Apolloinius 113C; see also 111D, 117B-D).
Funeral inscriptions speak of how Fate has "snatched away" the living to the place of Hades (IG 2.1062a.3; 11477.9; 4.620.2; 5.733.12).
Lucian uses a synonym of harpazo in the speech of a grieving father who cries out to his deceased son: "Dearest child, you are gone from me, dead, snatched away before your time" (Funerals 13).
Paul, therefore, may have chosen the word harpazo not to describe a literal snatching away or "rapture" but rather to make a clever pun or inversion on the common use of this word.
Rather than the expected picture of people being "snatched away" from life to death, Christians will be "snatched away" from life to life such that they do not face death.
(Rock hard!) Evidence #3: "to meet" Greek noun ἀπαντῆσις (apantêsis) does not refer generically to just any kind of meeting but is a technical term referring to the specific custom in Paul's day of sending a delegation of leading citizens--a reception party--outside the city "to meet" a visiting dignitary and then escort that person on the final part of their journey into the city.
These formal "receptions" typically involved the following elements:
1:Prominent citizens were chosen to be members of the delegation or reception party.
2:City leaders adopt a formal resolution to pay tribute to visiting dignitary and host formal reception in his honor.
3:These citizens would dress in their finest clothes (often white) and with laurel wreaths on their heads as they left the city to meet the visiting dignitary.
4:After meeting and greeting the visiting dignitary, reception part would escort this person the rest of his way into their city.
Sometimes the visiting dignitary would pronounce judgment on select prisoners, liberating some but sentencing others to execution.
Greek word apantêsis has this technical meaning not only in secular writings but also in its three NT occurrences:
Occurrence #1 of key word apantêsis: Matthew 25:6 (Parable of Wise & Foolish Virgins)
Occurrence #2 of key word apantêsis : Acts 28:15 (Paul's arrival in Rome)
Occurrence #3 of key word apantêsis : 1 Thess 4:17 "to meet the Lord in the air" means that the persecuted church plays the privileged role of being the delegation party that meets the descending Christ in the air and then, rather than go with Jesus to heaven for seven years (so Dispensationalists), escorts him to earth where Christ rules over the restored creation.
"Interpret scripture with scripture"
Matthew 24:37-41
(37) As it was in the days of Noah, so it will be at the coming of the Son of Man. (38) For in the days before the flood, people were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, up to the day Noah entered the ark; (39) and they knew nothing about what would happen until the flood came and took them all away. That is how it will be at the coming of the Son of Man. 40 Two men will be in the field; one will be taken and the other left. 41 Two women will be grinding with a hand mill; one will be taken and the other left.
(Parallel version: Luke 17:26-35)
Context is king!
In Noah's day:
Those taken away (i.e. "raptured") = unbelievers who perish in flood
Those who remain (i.e. not "raptured") = Noah & his family who live
Conclusion: I want to be 'left behind'!
In the coming of Son of Man: Emphasis added.
"That is how it will be at the coming of the Son of Man. Two men will be in the field; one will be taken [away in judgment like unbelievers in Noah's day] and the other left [behind to live like Noah and his family]. Two women will be grinding with a hand mill; one will be taken [away in judgment] and the other left [behind to live]"
Q: The Rapture: A Biblical Truth or Mistaken Teaching?
Yes, the Bible teaches that the church will be joined or "raptured" to Christ at his return such that there is a separation between believers and unbelievers.
No, the Bible does not teach that there will be a sudden disappearance or "rapture" of the church to heaven for seven years after which it returns to earth with Christ to participate in his 1000 year millennial reign.
How does your school explain the fact that 1 Thess 5 begins with the word "but", suggesting a continuation of the previous conversation? –
brmicke
Answer:
The particle δε (de) indicates a mild objection or simple transition and can sometimes be translated with "but" or "indeed, but" or "also". More often, however, it carries the mere force of a sentence's natural progression and as a result leaves little to be translated in English. Hebrew has a silent particle like that as well, albeit of slightly different function and origin: את ('et).
Our particle δε (de) frequently occurs with other particles in formulaic contexts: with μεν (men), which expresses affirmation, it forms a construct that means something like "indeed" or "if truly... then surely" (see our article on μεν, men, for an exhaustive look at this formula). With the copulative και (kai) it literally forms "and but" but takes on the meaning of "also".
https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/d/d-e.html#:~:text=Our%20particle%20%CE%B4%CE%B5%20(de)%20is,New%20Testament%3B%20see%20full%20concordance.
Our particle δε (de), which is translated "but" in the translation you are reading is used 2867 times in the New Testament; In his message to the believers in Thessalonica, Paul implores them to remain vigilant at all times, as the Lord's coming will be sudden and unexpected, likened to that of a "thief in the night." The early adherents of Jesus held the belief that his return was imminent within their own era.
For further use of the word δὲ.
NAS Exhaustive Concordance
Word Origin
a prim. word
Definition
but, and, now, (a connective or adversative particle)
NASB Translation
after (2), also (2), another* (8), even (4), even though (1), former* (1), however (6), moreover (1), moreover* (1), nevertheless (1), now (267), or (6), other (1), other hand (4), others* (3), partly (1), rather (1), so (12), suppose* (1), then (6), therefore (1), though (1), what (1), when (3), whereas (2), yes (1), yet (25).
Literary context. The word δὲ, which is used elsewhere in scripture as a connective or adversative particle":
https://biblehub.com/greek/1161.htm
Strong's Concordance 1161.de
de: but, and, now, (a connective or adversative particle)
Original Word: δέ
Part of Speech: Conjunction
Transliteration: de
Phonetic Spelling: (deh)
Definition: but, and, now, (a connective or adversative particle)
Usage: a weak adversative particle, generally placed second in its clause; but, on the other hand, and.
Matthew.1:2
GRK: Ἰσαάκ Ἰσαὰκ δὲ ἐγέννησεν τὸν
KJV: begat Isaac; and Isaac begat
INT: Issac Isaac moreover was father of
Matthew 1:3 Conj
GRK: Ἰούδας δὲ ἐγέννησεν τὸν
KJV: And Judas begat
INT: Judah moreover was father of
Matthew 1:4 Conj
GRK: Ἀρὰμ δὲ ἐγέννησεν τὸν
KJV: And Aram begat
INT: Ram moreover was father of
Matthew 1:5 Conj
GRK: Ῥαχάβ Βοὲς δὲ ἐγέννησεν τὸν
KJV: of Rachab; and Booz begat
INT: Rahab Boaz moreover was father of
These are just a few occurrences of the word δὲ.
Definitions from Oxford Languages
noun
1.
Grammar: a word used to connect clauses or sentences or to coordinate words in the same clause (e.g. and, but, if ).
2.
the action or an instance of two or more events or things occurring at the same point in time or space.
Strong's Exhaustive Concordance
also, and, but, moreover, now.
A primary particle (adversative or continuative); but, and, etc. -- also, and, but, moreover, now (often unexpressed in English).

Welcome to the site, could you please specify your perspective? It is extremely difficult to understand an answer sometimes without knowing the theological view of the person who answered.  For example I have been trying to always preface my answers by stating that my perspective and answer is based on eastern orthodox tradition and beliefs.

How does your school explain the fact that 1 Thess 5 begins with the word "but", suggesting a continuation of the previous conversation?
